# Time jumped forward

Tags: ros, syncronization, rostime, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi folks,

I am receiving some error messages from everything that uses planning_environment (OMPL, Trajectory Filter, you name it!), namely that the joint_states messages are discarded and I should turn DEBUG on. When I look at the DEBUG messages, I see a dominant "Time jumped forward by xxx for timer of period [0.010000], resetting timer". Although I don't think that that is the problem, I was curious about this message. What does it mean? Is it bad?

BTW I am currently distributing the nodes among at least 3 computers. Although they query a local ntp server every minute, keeping them in sync is a big problem. How influential is this on the tf synchronisation problems?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9281/time-jumped-forward/) by [Lorenzo Riano](https://answers.ros.org/users/155/lorenzo-riano/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1342 on 2011-03-03

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If synchronization between different contributing machines is off, this can generally cause a lot of problems with tf. The recommendation is to use chrony (http://chrony.tuxfamily.org/) instead of plain ntp for synchronization, as it is much more reliable.

There are quite a few posts on the mailing list about details:
http://ros-users.122217.n3.nabble.com/template/NamlServlet.jtp?macro=search_page&node=122217&query=chrony

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2011-03-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2